# SQL Server: How to loop through the Deleted table in update trigger and convert each row into JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, database-trigger

I created an `Update` trigger that gets the deleted rows as JSON and saves them into another table as a column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTrigger on [Table1]
FOR UPDATE 
AS
   DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = (SELECT * FROM Deleted FOR JSON PATH)
   INSERT INTO [Table2](Id, Record) VALUES (NEWID(), @json);
GO
```

I'd like to change the logic so that there is one insert into `Table2` for every row in the `Deleted` table. How can I loop through the `Deleted` table and convert each row into JSON and save it into `Table2`?

Comment: Do you know do column names in the `Deleted` table?

Comment: Yes I do. 1 uniqueidentifier, 1 datetime2, 4 varchar(max) columns. The column names could be faked for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following approach:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTrigger on [Table1]
FOR UPDATE 
AS
   INSERT INTO [Table2] (Id, Record) 
   SELECT 
      NEWID(),
      Record = (SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6 FOR JSON PATH)
   FROM Deleted
GO
```